# WordPress: Create Menu with Values from Corresponding Page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields on my pages to create a field called `page_color`. The field is a select that allows for 4 different values. In my menu, I would like pages to appear automatically and have a class `is-orange` or `is-green` (or whatever color) in the list item, based on the value the user has selected on the corresponding page. I am not certain the best way to approach (e.g., walker function, extending the `wp_nav_menu_items` function) and would appreciate some help/direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles across this, I will post the answer I found.

The route I used was creating my own Walker class and using `$item->object_id` to get the id of the corresponding page to then retrieve the value I need with ACF `get_field('field_name', id)` function.